# How to loop two sequential counters and display them cycle number of the loop

Tags: javascript, repeat, countdowntimer

I have an application that needs to display on an HTML-screen two countdown timers, one after the other, each countdown timer has its own duration taken from a database.
This sequence of displaying the two countdown timers needs to be repeated a certain number of times, the value of which is also taken from the database.

I am an absolute noob in JavaScript and I'm struggling to find a way to:

1. display the number of the cycle;
2. run both timers one after the other, so the second timer only starting when the first timer has finished.

All displays and timers start running at the same time and not sequentially and the repeat number is displayed immediately with its end value and not increasing in a step-by-step manner.

Can anyone help me out on this?

I am working on the basis of this JavaScript:

```
    <script>
      var Repeats = {{ fase['rep'] }};
      var timeleftEdge = {{ fase['edge'] }};
      var timeleftFace = {{ fase['face'] }};

      for (let index = 1; index <= Repeats; index++) {
            document.getElementById("RepeatCounter").innerHTML = "Herhaling : " + index.toFixed(0) + "e keer";
            RunTimer(timeleftEdge, 'countdownEdge', 'Edge');
            RunTimer(timeleftFace, 'countdownFace', 'Face');
        }

      function RunTimer(timeleft, DIV_ID, Type) {
        var Timer = setInterval(function(){
          if(timeleft <= 0){
            clearInterval(Timer);
            document.getElementById(DIV_ID).innerHTML = "Klaar";
          } else {
            document.getElementById(DIV_ID).innerHTML = Type + " :   " + timeleft.toFixed(1) + " seconden te gaan";
          }
          timeleft -= 0.1;
        }, 100);
      }
    </script>
```

I have tried to use Promise, async/await, but cannot make it work.

Runable Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title> Timer Scherm </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        
        
    <h1> Timer Scherm </h1>
    </br>

    <div class="row mb-3 text-left">
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-1 themed-grid-col"><h5>Step: 3</h5></div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 themed-grid-col"><h5>Fase: 15m 3 Sets Rapid</h5></div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-2 themed-grid-col"><h5>Edge: 3.0 sec.</h5></div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-2 themed-grid-col"><h5>Face: 6.0 sec.</h5></div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-2 themed-grid-col"><h5>Reps: 3 times</h5></div>
    </div>

    <h1 class="text-primary">
      <p id="RepeatCounter"></p>
    </h1>

    </br>

    <h1 class="text-danger">
      <div id="countdownEdge"></div>
    </h1>

    </br>

    <h1 class="text-success">
        <div id="countdownFace"></div>
    </h1>

    <script>
      var Repeats = 3;
      var timeleftEdge = 3.0;
      var timeleftFace = 6.0;

      for (let index = 1; index <= Repeats; index++) {
            document.getElementById("RepeatCounter").innerHTML = "Repeat : " + index.toFixed(0) + " time";
            RunTimer(timeleftEdge, 'countdownEdge', 'Edge');
            RunTimer(timeleftFace, 'countdownFace', 'Face');
        }

      function RunTimer(timeleft, DIV_ID, Type) {
        var Timer = setInterval(function(){
          if(timeleft <= 0){
            clearInterval(Timer);
            document.getElementById(DIV_ID).innerHTML = "Ready";
          } else {
            document.getElementById(DIV_ID).innerHTML = Type + " :   " + timeleft.toFixed(1) + " seconds remaining";
          }
          timeleft -= 0.1;
        }, 100);
      }
    </script>



    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="/static/js/jquery-3.7.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. Remove the `{{ fase['rep'] }}` and replace with some dummy data and please include your HTML/

Comment: you won't be able to do this quite like you're writing it.  SetInterval will be fine for one, but the setting is asynchronous and returns immediately so the second interval will start immediately.  What you could do is var x = setInterval blah blah and then in the 2nd timer check if the first timer is running and only increment if it isn't.

Comment: I added a runable example of the HTML + Java Script

Comment: @JohnLord : That will indeed work, I remind I did that in one of my trial-and-error approaches.
But I could not get the repeats work across those two timers. The reps again were running their own asynchronous run.

So I'm actually looking for a way to make the 3 steps in the code synchronous.

1. First show the rep-counter
2. Start timer 1
3. Once timer 1 has finished, start timer 2.
4. Once timer 2 has finished, increase the rep-counter until the maximum number of reps has been reached.

Comment: if they aren't ever running at the same time then you only actually need one timer, and that will make your code much simpler to write and debug.

Comment: @JohnLord as you see in the code I posted above, there is actually only one function running the timer, which is being called twice. So could you Guide me with your thoughts on how to make this timer run twice in sequence within a loop of a set number of repeats, which as you say is so much simpeler to write.

Comment: sure.  If I understand correctly you only need one to decrement at a time.
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if (timeleftEdge <= 0) {
        timeleftFace -= .1;
    } else {
        timeleftEdge -= .1;
    }
}, 100)
Of course you would need a 3rd variable for tracking the loops you need to do and reset the counters each time it decrements.